# jQuery Modal Example with .Net 2.0 Infragistics Grid

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, infragistics, ignite-ui

I'm new to jQuery (I must have had my head buried in sand for the last few years!) and I'm wondering if I could use it with an Infragistics grid for updating and inserting instead of the edit row template. We're currently constrained to using the 2.0 framework, and I'm stuck with the infra grids as well.

- Does anyone know if this is possible?
- Do you think this is a bad/good idea?
- Any good sample/walk-throughs out
  there?

Any, and all, advice/opinions appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the WebDialogWindow in infragistics toolset itself. I support both, modal and non-modal modes and is a control container so you can put anything in there.

You can handle the template open client side event, cancel the default one and show the WebDialogWindow, let the user name changes and once they are done you can take values from those editors and update the grid cells. You can learn more about the WebDialogWindow [here](http://community.infragistics.com/aspnet/media/default.aspx?tags=WebDialogWindow).

HTH.

Taz.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Looks quite interesting.  I'm liking as alternative, btu I've did a bit more research into jQuery and I lioke the idea of the smaller footprint by ditching infragistics completely.

Comment: Do you have an specific examples of the dialog window updating the webgrid directly?

Comment: Not a dialog window, check this out
http://samples.infragistics.com/2009.1/WebFeatureBrowser/contents.aspx?showCode=True&t=WebGrid/RowEditTemplates/RowEditTemplates.aspx~srcview.aspx?path=../webfeaturebrowservb/WebGrid/RowEditTemplates/RowEditTemplates.src~srcview.aspx?path=WebGrid/RowEditTemplates/

Comment: Thanks for that,  but I'm not too keen on the edit templates.  Had bother with them in the past and I try to avoid them now!